# `sudo npm install -g npm` is supposedly a bad idea, but doesn't work without `sudo`

Tags: node.js, npm, global, npm-install, access-rights

I'm always struggling with updating node / npm packages or npm itself.

I have an Ubuntu machine where I have a global npm install, which I want to update.

`npm install -g npm` results in all sorts of '/usr/local/lib' access permission denied errors.

I can use `sudo` but then the `~/.npm` dir in my default user account's home dir is owned by root, not by me. Which I assume will give trouble when installing or updating packages, and seems overall a bad idea anyway. I am using and running npm as me, not as root.

Upon searching I find several half-baked workarounds for this but I have a strong impression I'm doing something wrong. Or maybe I just misunderstand the issue at hand. I have trouble believing that a long term and widely used project like `npm` would suffer from such basic shortcomings?

What is the most correct, simple way to install npm globally on a regular linux environment?

Comment: Manually change npm’s default directory always worked for me https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally

Comment: But in my opinion the best way is to use docker and don't install npm on your system.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the Ubuntu's node and npm version.

Ubuntu's repository locks you in one verson of node, which then also limits your available version of npm.

Either use node managers like [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) or [n](https://github.com/tj/n). They allow changing your node version with one command.

Or even [docker containers](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/). With Dockerfile you can create environments that mimick your production environment (or which basically is the same as production if you deploy your apps as docker containers).

Comment: Thanks, will look into nvm or n. As for docker containers, isn't the idea of docker containers that it runs isolated in a kind of sandbox, which would make it hard to interact with the rest of my system? (apologies if this is a dumb question, my docker experience is very limited)

Comment: @Joey, I have the same problem. Can you please tell me how you fixed this in the end? I'd be surprised if the only fix involves installing something in addition to node.js and npm. I've used node.js and npm for a few years but I've never had to go that deep into it. I had to re-install node.js and npm as I had a new Mac, which is why I'm encountering these problems. I also don't understand the reason why "sudo" is a bad idea. Any help is very much appreciated.